# Pattern for grammar translation

Tags: php

We have a multi language website, that uses database for some data. So for example, I would have a table called tbl_country, and I could have: United States (english), Estados Unidos (spanish) or New Zealand (english), Nueva Zelandia (spanish). etc..

So our translations would be:

```
<?= sprintf(t('Work in %s'), $countryName) ?>
```

The problem I have, is that in different languages, this translation may require extra words, or it could have genders. For example:

```
Work in Canada (English)
Trabalhar no Canada (Portuguese)



Work in Ireland (English)
Trabalhar na Irlanda (Portuguese)
```

Apart from the obvious solution of translating the whole phrase, is there any other way of archiving this? Is there any kind of pattern?

Answer (score 2):

Make a list of all the texts in your website and then prepare another list or make two columns in your original list which contains corresponding translations of your first list/column. This is the usual practise. If you are looking for perfect machine based translation than it is not possible as of now because different languages have different kinds of words for various expressions and it is not possible for machines to know which exact word to use and if you are trying to make your own machine translation service then good luck with that.